# if (preg_match) not finding a variable

Tags: laravel

I am trying to make an API in laravel 10 that can read a name variable from different kinds of scripts. Only my code doesn't seem to work with the test python code that I wrote. I have figured out that the problem lies within the `if(preg_match)` for the python section as I was able to return strings to the console from everywhere else in the code`

My controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class PluginAPIController extends Controller
{
    public function list()
    {
        $plugins = File::files(public_path('testplugins'));

        $names = [];

        foreach ($plugins as $file) {
            $extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $contents = File::get($file);
            $matches = [];

            if($extension == "php"){
                preg_match('/\$name\s*=\s*\'(.*)\';/i', $contents, $matches);
                if (isset($matches[1])) {
                    $names[] = $matches[1];
                }
            }elseif ($extension == "js") {
                preg_match('/var\s+name\s*=\s*[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"];/i', $contents, $matches);
                if (isset($matches[1])) {
                    $names[] = $matches[1];
                }
            }elseif ($extension == 'py') {
                exec("python -c \"exec(open('$file').read())\" 2>&1", $output, $return);
                foreach ($output as $line) {
                    if (preg_match('/^name\s*=\s*[\'"](.*?)[\'"]$/i', $line, $matches)) {
                        return('I work');
                        $names[] = $matches[1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return($names);

    }
```

My python file

```py
name = "Python test"

print(name);
```

What the console currently gives me

```json
[
    "test",
    "test2",
    "js test"
]
```

Comment: Are you sure the issue is that `if(preg_match(...))`? `$line = 'name = "Python test"'`, then `preg_match('/^name\s*=\s*[\'"](.*?)[\'"]$/i', $line, $matches)`, and finally `$matches[1]` properly shows `"Python test"`. You do have a `return('I work');` statement before `$names[] = $matches[1]`, and a `return` statement will stop subsequent code execution...

Comment: the return is just there for testing. and as you can see in console it doesn't acctually return anything. if I put that return somewhere else it runs fine it's just in the if statment that it doesn't run. that's how I know there is something wrong with it

Comment: Ok. So what debugging have you done? I've already shown that `$line = 'name = "Python test"';` followed by  `if(preg_match( /* your code */)) { ... }` works as expected, so you're going to need to debug _why_ it doesn't work in your code... As written, I can't reproduce your issue... Use some breakpoints, or `dd()` or `Log::info()` statements to analyze what your code is doing and why it's not working.